# I have an unidentified press-fit nut that I need to reproduce, can anyone tell me how to find this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, fasteners, connections

I received these fittings as part of a package, but now we need more of them. Can anyone identify this assembly, or even better help me learn how to recreate it? My coworkers and I are stumped.

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38qb9.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Search for M8 press fit nuts or M6 - not sure

Comment: Measurements may be useful, or even required.

Comment: These are also referred to as "Broach nuts" in some industries.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, look up Rivnuts.

Answer (score 1):

There's really not enough information to be certain, but the images seem to match TR Fastenings' "[Self Clinch Non-Locking Mini Squeezed Nut](https://www.trfastenings.com/Products/Catalogue/nuts/Hank-Self-Clinch-Nuts/Non-Locking-Mini-Squeezed)"

N.B. It also looks to have been improperly installed, as the 'spiked' diameter should be fully embedded in the bulk material.

Answer (score 0):

Those are "press fit" or "captive" nuts. Mcmaster Carr should have whatever your looking for.